# shiny Ui - refer to same plot multiple times

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, plotly

I built a shiny app which, eventually, should work in multiple languages.

Hence, in my UI, I want to refer to the same plots multiple times.

However, it seems that I can only refer to the outplut$plot once - if I do so multiple times, no plot is visible.

So my questions is: how do I refer to the same plot from the UI multiple times?

Please find a minimum working example below. If I comment "plot2" in the UI out, it works. If I dont, both plots disappear.

best wishes from berlin (:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

y <- c(1:30)
x <- c(1:30)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(y, x))

plot <- renderPlotly(
    ggplotly(
        ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
            geom_point() 
    )
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    "plot1", 
                       plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%"), 
    # "plot2",
    #                    plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%")

               
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        ggplotly(
            ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
                geom_point()
        )
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't use the same output twice, as the plots would then have the same `ID` in html. Also, it is not clear why you'd need to do so for your specific problem, do you need to display the same plot twice?

Otherwise, you can try to add the 'language-related' logic to the server side, maybe? e.g

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if (current_language() == 'English') {
        ...
    } else {
        ... 
    }
})
```

As a workaround you could try to save the plot to an object, e.g.

```
plot <- ggplotly(
            ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
                geom_point()
)
```

Then use it to create two outputs (with different names though)

Comment: bonsoir claude & merci pour ton avis (:  
@why? i basically replicated the app four times and created for panels for each of the four languages.. do you know of a smarter method of the top of your head? @replication that is what i figured, thanks for the confirmation

Comment: oh, I thought the user chooses the language of entire app, but seems like you show all the elements at once. I mean, you could go fancy and create all elements in a loop or something... but if the app is not huge I'd just replicate the needed outputs as you did.

Comment: nah, I just used navbarPage and four different navbarMenus .. jut stumbled over shiny.i18n, tho and thought about implementing it..